# Почему .json() возвращает промис?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

При использовании `fetch` хочу получить данные, однако при следующем использовании нашёл одну интересную вещь:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => console.log(response.json())) // [object Promise] { ... }
```

Сам вопрос заключается в следующем: почему `response.json()` возвращает промис, а не данные из запроса? т.к. если воспользоваться подходом ниже, то всё работает как надо

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json)) // данные из запроса
```

Comment: а почему ты думал, что `.json` возвращает не Promise? Собственно, об этом [явно в справке указано](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дам кусочек [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch)

> Процесс получения ответа обычно происходит в два этапа.
>
> Во-первых, promise выполняется с объектом встроенного класса Response
> в качестве результата, как только сервер пришлёт заголовки ответа.
>
> На этом этапе мы можем проверить статус HTTP-запроса и определить,
> выполнился ли он успешно, а также посмотреть заголовки, но пока без
> тела ответ