# Почему response.json( ) после fetch асинхронен?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Во время работы с Fetch api возник вопрос, почему response.json( ) возращает промис? Мы ведь не посылаем никаких данных на сервер, просто нужно распарсить json, который мы получили в ответе от сервера. Для чего так было сделано? Объясните пожалуйста недалёкому

Comment: Возможно потому, что JSON может быть в мегабайт.. или даже гигабайт)

Comment: «который мы получили» — нет, ещё не получили, он ещё скачивается, поэтому необходимо асинхронно дождаться завершения скачивания

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему .json() возвращает промис?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177712/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-json-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81)